What is this usage of 見切られた?

小柄な彼は主に尾行調査が得意で、なんでもない日は自ら進んで掃除もこなす働き者。
何故そんなに掃除が好きかと問えば、「誰もやらないからやってるだけです」と見切られたことがある————

The character is describing a collague. In the bottom part, he says "After I asked him why he likes cleaning, he told me I'm only doing it because no one else is doing it"
But why is 見切られた used?  As far I know it's largely used for seeing?

Frankly speaking, this doesn't seem like a typical usage of 見切る. It's either simply incorrect or depends on broader context. Assuming it's not a typo:

There's a possibility that 見切る is being used in the sense of 見限る/見捨てる ("to give up on"). In this case, his response might have carried a nuance like "What kind of question is this, you haven't even noticed why I clean my room? How disappointing".

Another possibility is that 見切る is being used in the sense of 見透かす/全部把握する/完全に理解する ("to see through/grasp completely"). In this case, his response might have been more like "Oh, I understand the intention behind your question—so you want to leave the cleaning to me, huh?".


If neither interpretation fits the context well, I recommend not worrying too much about this use of 見切る.

If I'm not mistaken, 見切る could basically mean through see through something or figure out something.
In this case, と見切られたことがある could be translated is "he could see that" or "he understood that" or "he realized that". Basically, giving the sense that there's writing on the wall, and he can see through the bullshit and realize this fact.
Another example of 見切る being used this way is "彼は唯一{ゆいいつ}の正{ただ}しい選択{せんたく}を見切ってた" (He could see [through all the vagaries and bullshit] what the one correct path was.)
